# PayPal live environment error: PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED | The merchant account is restricted

Tags: paypal

I am using @paypal/checkout-server-sdk and when I use live enviroment I get this error:

```
    text: `{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/payee","location":"body","issue":"PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED","description":"The merchant account is restricted."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"17aeec9c490da","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}`,        
    statusCode: 422,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '487',
      connection: 'close',
      date: 'Thu, 16 Sep 2021 15:39:15 GMT',
      application_id: 'APP-22708535S4154154M',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      caller_acct_num: 'HCYCS3MA4HASE',
      'paypal-debug-id': '17aeec9c490da',
      http_x_pp_az_locator: 'ccg14.slc',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
    }
  }
}
```

Code: http://hastebin.com/ixotativig.js

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems like a support issue, and not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming matter. As the error's details say:

```json
{
  "field": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/payee",
  "location": "body",
  "issue": "PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED",
  "description": "The merchant account is restricted."
}
```

So, log into the live merchant account at [www.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com) to review information about the restriction and steps to resolve it. Contact PayPal if you need support.

Comment: I think that was that even though I wanted to be sure thanks I will test